Postgres Upsert Returning with FOR UPDATE lock
I have a table that records requests to an external API for data enrichment. I want to ensure that there is only one row for a given entity with status = 'Pending' (meaning a process is doing the work.) With a unique constraint, I have that covered.
Now I want to pull out the pending request WITH FOR UPDATE to ensure that only one process is using it at a time, in case two async jobs try to work on the same request.
I can INSERT […] ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING for the upsert. Annoyingly, this returns nothing if there is an existing row so I can't rely on RETURNING, but I can then SELECT […] WITH FOR UPDATE NOWAIT to ensure that only on process can hold it.
Can I do this in one statement?
Essentially I would like to do this:
INSERT […] ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING * WITH FOR UPDATE NOWAIT


Why not use two statements, one that inserts (or does nothing) and a second one to lock the row?

I could, but I'd prefer to do it atomically!

It will be atomic, if you perform both statements in the same REPEATABLE READ transaction.
